# Set two decimal places after AVG function inside PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, pivot, average

```
SELECT 
   Student, [English], [Mathematics], [Science], [Programming], [History]
FROM
(
   SELECT  
       Grades, Subject, Student
   FROM    
       Grade_Report
) AS sourcetable
PIVOT
(
   AVG(Grades)
   FOR [Subject] IN ([English], [Mathematics], [Science], [Programming], [History])
) AS pivoted
```

The output keeps being 95.000000

I tried using AVG( CAST(Grades AS Decimal(10,2) ) ) inside the pivot, and it keeps returning a syntax error about (.

Tried using CAST AS DECIMAL inside the FROM subquery, but it just keeps putting the same 00000 output.
CAST AS FLOAT works but I need two decimal places and it eliminates trailing 0s

Using ROUND(AVG) inside the pivot ends up being unrecognized aggregate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want two decimal positions for all your numbers, even if these digits are not significant. This reads like a pure formatting issue.

I would recommend `format()`:

```
SELECT Student, 
    format([English],     '0.00') as [English], 
    format([Mathematics], '0.00') as [Mathematics],
    format([Science],     '0.00') as [Science],
    format([Programming], '0.00') as [Programming],
    format([History],     '0.00') as [History]
FROM ...
```

Note that this turns the numbers to strings - which seems to be what you are actually asking here.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I never knew it was possible to touch those pivoting values. Now I tried using CAST on them and it works too, what do you recommend?